# sql server unclosed quotation mark because insert a string with 's

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, quotation-marks

I am trying to write extended properties to each column of a table from python.
Here is my code:

```
for i in dat.columns:
    sql_query = """\
                EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty
                     @name = N'Description',
                     @value = N'{}',
                     @level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = '{}',
                     @level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = '{}',
                     @level2type = N'Column', @level2name = '{}'
                """.format(dat[i][0], db, tb, i)
```

Here dat[i][0] contains the description for each column. However, one of the description is like balabalabala...student's program...balabalabal, where there is a single ' in the description and it cause an error.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 's'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '\n                    '. (105)")
```

How to handle this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't the usual ways of handling this work with Python?

Comment: Whenever I insert a string that contains a single-quote character in SQL Server, I use two consecutive single quotes.  In your case, the description would be `Balabalabalabala... student''s program, balabalabala.`  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Brian works very well. Make it a solution here. I will vote and make it the answer. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever inserting a string that contains a single-quote character in SQL Server, use two consecutive single quotes. In your case, the description would be:

```
'Balabalabalabala... student''s program, balabalabala.'
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use CHAR(39) instead of ' in your code.

Comment: Curiously, why do you recommend using `Char(39)` (39 being the ASCII code of the single-quote) instead of the single-quote character itself?

Comment: Your case is pretty simple. But, if you have way complex string, concatenations or dynamic sql used, I strongly recommend to use char(39) instead to make code readable, safer. And, sometimes it is impossible to solve problems using N level of single quotes